# How can I get type narrowing to work here?`

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

I'm not getting the result I expected from narrowing on a union type. Here's a snippet which captures the issue:

```js
interface A {
    a : number;
}

interface B {
    b : string;
}

const isAnA = (arg : A | B) : arg is A => {
    return "a" in arg;
}

const applyFunc = <T>(func : (x : T) => number, arg : T) => {
    return func(arg)
}

const doTheThing = (arg : A | B) => {
    let f;
    if (isAnA(arg)) {
        f = (x : A) => x.a * 2;
    } else {
        f = (x : B) => parseInt(x.b) * 2;
    }
    return applyFunc(f, arg);
}
```

What I expected to happen here was that the `isAnA()` typeguard would let the compiler know that `f` has type `(x : A) => number` if `arg` is an `A`, and type `(x : B) => number` if `arg` is a `B`, allowing `applyFunc` to be called on `arg` and `f` together.

However, I get this from the compiler:

```
  Type '(x: B) => number' is not assignable to type '(x: A) => number'.
    Types of parameters 'x' and 'x' are incompatible.
      Property 'b' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'.
```

Is there any way to get this working other than explicitly typeguarding the call to `applyFunc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you want to tell Typescript that two variables have correlated types, i.e. *"either `arg` is `A` and `func` accepts `A`, or `arg` is `B` and `func` accepts `B`"*, then they need to be properties of some object with a discriminated union type:

```
{arg: A, func: (x: A) => number} | {arg: B, func: (x: B) => number}
```

To make it actually work in your code, the discriminated union needs to be built using a distributive conditional type, so the compiler won't complain about the `applyFuncWithObject` function. I solved this by making `ArgAndFunc` a parameterised type, so the discriminated union above is `ArgAndFunc<A | B>`.

```
type ArgAndFunc<T> = T extends unknown ? {arg: T, func: (x: T) => number} : never

function applyFuncWithObject<T>(obj: ArgAndFunc<T>) {
    // or directly: return obj.func(obj.arg)
    return applyFunc(obj.func, obj.arg);
}

function doTheThing(arg: A | B) {
    let obj: ArgAndFunc<A | B>;
    if(isAnA(arg)) {
        obj = {arg, func: (x: A) => x.a * 2};
    } else {
        obj = {arg, func: (x: B) => parseInt(x.b) * 2};
    }
    return applyFuncWithObject<A | B>(obj);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7LgLmSAVwFsAjaAbmQF8AoUSWRFAIU2RLwGcwpQBzSrRgEQCMMAD2IZME6oQqABRwofPOgA+yZgEo8KvjM5pMNZOeRQIYAlGkAiOPZnSD5GkJFjJrgA6+AGwBPADEvAB4AFQA+RWFRPEUADzxInWQAXmj8YjIoABpsVVT0jDMLKxs7ZHiEZVUdDxoaMCDfFFRVeQATMNEo7IzkSOQIJMgQbuMRAGsQCQB3aQB+TANUwtrElOH0rJzSaCpkPBAIADdoZtrxKWx-YL6EAHVgMAALAHkSACsIMQGigkv3UXUmTwGpXK5gA9DDkBIoMhusArGJgnhKrZpMCfgA6WpA354gyNCyWazY+6BUJeIn42qFXEkhruWg0G4+ZESSLvCC8-j1NQmLS6UzkgLWBEgtBg3oRTTaaLucnAGCKWTyJSkqHk8m4zJrVSbLzbdR7bJJEnIABUyAATFQVRZjhAApwUGU9RYDUMMAYTQlkMk8GL9r4VB6AJLgZJ4kjpO2O53mWjkrHVOAPWmiV4fb5-AGK5ixXE6Nk0IA)

I don't know if this will meet your needs exactly, since it doesn't allow you to pass `arg` and `func` as two separate arguments anywhere (without writing a generic helper function like `applyFuncWithObject`). On the other hand, if you do need to pass `arg` and `func` together in multiple places then passing a single object instead will probably simplify your code.

Comment: This isn't _exactly_ what I was looking for, but it accomplishes the goal without repetition of the execution logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One thing to do would be to use the conditional operator instead - TypeScript works best when reassignment is minimized. But there's still the problem that you have the type `(x: A =>  number) | (x: B) => number)` is undesirably separated from the type of the argument (`A | B`).

I think the best approach here would be to invoke the function needed inside the narrowed condition, to avoid having to re-narrow later, eg:

```
const doTheThing = (arg: A | B) => {
    return isAnA(arg)
        ? applyFunc((x: A) => x.a * 2, arg)
        : applyFunc((x: B) => parseInt(x.b) * 2, arg);
}
```

Comment: This is the sort of solution I was referring to when I said I'd like to avoid explicitly typeguarding the call, since it leads to repetition of the call to applyFunc. In my code that I ran into this issue with I ended up doing that, but I'd prefer to avoid repeating myself.

Comment: @DavisYoshida I believe this is good solution. Union of functions types is a hard type to deal with. Most of the time it is unuseful, because you want an intersection or in other words - overloading. AFAIK, there is no elegat and type safe solution.

Comment: @captain-yossarian I agree it's correct. If the answer is that you _cannot_ accomplish it without duplicating the code for the function call, then I'll accept it as the answer. I'd appreciate a pointer to something in the typescript docs indicating what the limitation is though.